# Creating Accordians in Wordpress Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, loop

I am creating a wordpress theme in which there is a section "**HUMOUR**". In this section i've created **accordians**, in which the 1st accordian is in **class="active"** and rest don't.

for e.g

```
<dl>

                        <dt class="active"> 
                            <h1 class="link_heading">
                                What are Benifits ?
                            </h1>
                            <div>
                                <img src="images/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down">
                                <img src="images/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up" style="display: none;">
                            </div>                                  
                        </dt>                       
                        <dd style="display: block;">
                            <p>lorem ipsumdolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elitseddo eiusmod tempor incididunt lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elit seddo eiusmod
                            </p>
                        </dd>

                        <dt class="">                           
                            <h1 class="link_heading">
                                CAN I OPT OUT ?
                            </h1>
                            <div>
                                <img src="images/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down" style="display: none;">
                                <img src="images/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up" style="display: block;">
                            </div>  
                        </dt>
                        <dd style="display: none;">
                            <p>lorem ipsumdolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elitseddo eiusmod tempor incididunt lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elit seddo eiusmod</p>
                        </dd>

                        <dt class="">
                            <h1 class="link_heading">
                                IS MY CAPITAL SAFE&nbsp;?
                            </h1>
                            <div>
                                <img src="images/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down" style="display: none;">
                                <img src="images/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up" style="display: block;">
                            </div>
                        </dt>
                        <dd style="display: none;">
                            <p>lorem ipsumdolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elitseddo eiusmod tempor incididunt lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elit seddo eiusmod</p>
                        </dd>

                        <dt class="">
                            <h1 class="link_heading">
                                WHAT IS THE RISK&nbsp;?
                            </h1>
                            <div>
                                <img src="images/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down" style="display: none;">
                                <img src="images/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up" style="display: block;">
                            </div>  
                        </dt>
                        <dd style="display: none;">
                            <p>lorem ipsumdolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elitseddo eiusmod tempor incididunt lorem ipsum dolor sitamet consectetur adipisicing elit seddo eiusmod</p>
                        </dd>
                    </dl>
```

This is required **Accordian**

[image]

While creating same in wordpress its not displaying 1st post in **class="active"**. Also, its not working as expected.

i.e

```
<dl>
                                <dt id="post-224">  
                    <h1 class="link_heading">WHAT IS THE RISK ?</h1>
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/cultcapital-wp/images/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down">
                        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/cultcapital-wp/images/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up">
                    </div>                                  
                </dt>                       
                <dd style="display: block;">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam facilisis nisi in ligula semper rutrum. Aliquam placerat sapien dolor, non tristique massa ultrices sit amet.                    </p>
                </dd>
                                <dt id="post-222">  
                    <h1 class="link_heading">IS MY CAPITAL SAFE ?</h1>
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/cultcapital-wp/images/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down">
                        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/cultcapital-wp/images/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up">
                    </div>                                  
                </dt>                       
                <dd style="display: none;">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam facilisis nisi in ligula semper rutrum. Aliquam placerat sapien dolor, non tristique massa ultrices sit amet.                    </p>
                </dd>
                                <dt id="post-220">  
                    <h1 class="link_heading">CAN I OPT OUT ?</h1>
                    <div>
                        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/cultcapital-wp/images/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down">
                        <img src="http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/cultcapital-wp/images/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up">
                    </div>                                  
                </dt>                       
                <dd style="display: none;">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam facilisis nisi in ligula semper rutrum. Aliquam placerat sapien dolor, non tristique massa ultrices sit amet.                    </p>
                </dd>
                            </dl>
```

This is my preview

[image]

I've used custom post type to display accordians in which there is title and an excerpt. This is my code.

```
<div class="humour">
            <h1 class="section_heading"> HUMOUR ON INDIAN INVESTMENT </h1>
            <dl>
                <?php 
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'humour'
                    );
                $humour_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($humour_query->have_posts()) : while($humour_query->have_posts()) : $humour_query->the_post(); 
                ?>
                <dt id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">   
                    <h1 class="link_heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                    <div>
                        <img src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down"/>
                        <img src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up"/>
                    </div>                                  
                </dt>                       
                <dd>
                    <p>
                        <?php  
                            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                            echo string_limit_words($excerpt,25); 
                        ?>
                    </p>
                </dd>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            </dl>
        </div>
```

I want when user publish any post then it will check if its 1st post or not and if it is 1st post i.e current latest post then it will add class="active" to it and will leave rest posts as it is. I don't know exactly what should i do to achieve this task. Anybody please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per you described, What I have got is you want to **add class** `active` to **last published post by the user**.

By seeing your `output` and `HTML`, It seems that `active` class is missing.

So to achieve that, we will add one dummy condition that will print `class="active"`. I would also suggest that modify your `$arg` and make in `DESC` order to get last published post first.

Your final code will be something like this :

```
    <div class="humour">
        <h1 class="section_heading"> HUMOUR ON INDIAN INVESTMENT </h1>
        <dl>
            <?php 
                $args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'humour',
                        'order'     => 'DESC' //Add order to get post in DESC order
                        );
                $humour_query = new WP_Query($args);
                $i=0; //Take variable and assign it 0
                if ($humour_query->have_posts()) : while($humour_query->have_posts()) : $humour_query->the_post(); 
            ?>
            <?php 
                if($i==0): //This condition will be true only once as I have added increament at the end
                    echo "<dt id='post-".the_ID()."' class='active'>";
                else:   
            ?>
            <dt id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            endif;  
                <h1 class="link_heading"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
                <div>
                    <img src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/arrowdown.png" class="arrow" id="down"/>
                    <img src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/arrowup.png" class="arrow" id="up"/>
                </div>                                  
            </dt>                       
            <dd>
                <p>
                    <?php  
                        $excerpt = get_the_excerpt();
                        echo string_limit_words($excerpt,25); 
                    ?>
                </p>
            </dd>
            <?php 
            $i++; //Incremented that variable so class wont be added from second post
            endwhile; 
            endif; ?>
        </dl>
    </div>
```

**NOTE:** I have assumed that accordion is working with class `active`.

Comment: Glad it worked for you .. Happy Coding :)